# get/set asp.TextBox value in aspx file in <script runat=server>

Tags: asp.net

Hello I'm trying to access a textbox value in aspx page in script tag which is runat server but i can't access that property.

```
<asp:Label ID="wssName" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>


<script runat="server">
string fg = wss.Text;
</script>
```

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: are you trying to  access the texbox value or label value as per your code?????? If more you can try document.getElementById("wssName");

Comment: actually i want to access both a label and a textbox

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 document.getElementById('wssName').textContent
```

Answer (score 0):

To access asp.net control in script at client side tag we need to use control client id which is generated automatically until we have not set it static.

In your case you can access by using below snippet

```
var label = document.getElementById('<%= wssName.ClientID %>');
//to set text 
label.text('abc');
//to get value
var text = label.text();
```